# Rebuilding navigated page with new state

Tags: user-interface, flutter, navigation, material-design, state

I have a widget called `Classroom`, and in this widget has a button that navigattes you to another page called `ButtonPage`. It has only one button that triggers a function which affects `Classroom`'s state. It works perfectly. But the problem is that I also want to change `LightButton`'s color with the updated state in `Classroom` widget. Here is codes.

### Classroom

```js
class Classroom extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ClassroomState createState() => _ClassroomState();
}

class _ClassroomState extends State<Classroom> {
  bool isLightOn = false;
  final List<String> lightColor = ["red", "green", "blue"];
  String currentItem = "red";

  void onButtonPress() {
    setState(() {
      isLightOn = isLightOn;
    });
  }

  void selectItem(String selectedItem) {
    setState(() {
      currentItem = selectedItem;
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          LightBulb(
            isLightOn: isLightOn,
            currentItem: currentItem,
          ),
          Container(
            child: MaterialButton(
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text("Go to button's page"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return ButtonPage(
                    isLightOn: isLightOn,
                    onButtonPress: onButtonPress,
                  );
                }));
              },
            ),
          ),
          LightColorSelector(
            selectItem: selectItem,
            currentItem: currentItem,
            lightColor: lightColor,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

### ButtonPage

```js
class ButtonPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isLightOn;
  final VoidCallback onButtonPress;

  const ButtonPage({this.isLightOn, this.onButtonPress});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Button Page"),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Container(
        child: LightButton(
          isLightOn: isLightOn,
          onButtonPress: onButtonPress,
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

---

### LightButton

```js
class LightButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isLightOn;
  final VoidCallback onButtonPress;

  const LightButton({this.isLightOn, this.onButtonPress});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: MaterialButton(
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        color: Colors.blue,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        child:
            isLightOn ?? false ? Text("Turn light off") : Text("Turn light on"),
        onPressed: () {
          onButtonPress();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I click `MaterialButton` which is labeled as `Go to button's page`, it navigates me to `ButtonPage` with `isLightOn` and `onButtonPress` variables. In `LightButton`, when `onButtonPress` is triggered, it rebuild only previous page. That's why `Light Button`'s label isn't changed. How can I make it affected?

Comment: This is because Navigation doesn't work that way. The "Go to button's page" onPressed function doesn't get called each time your Classroom rebuilds. In this example it might be better to use a Provider + ValueNotifier. Or change ButtonPage to Stateful and add a isLightOn state there too that will be passed to the LightButton.

Comment: Can you give me an example solution with provide+valunotifier? If you can it will be awesome.